# Postfix: How can I handle incoming mail for a single address, not the entire domain?

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, email-server

I've gotten my employer to configure the company-wide Exchange server to forward `servicebot@example.com` to `servicebot@asriel.example.com`, a host I control.  So far, so good.  My Postfix configuration is pretty standard:

```
inet_interfaces = all
myhostname = asriel.example.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydomain = example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $myhostname.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost = outbound.example.com
...etc.
```

and a simple redirect in /etc/aliases

`servicebot: davidw`

Now, I don't actually want to handle email for $mydomain, because any **outgoing** email from `asriel.example.com` should not be delivered to the localhost (unless it's a local account, like `root` or `davidw`).  Outgoing mail should instead go to the relayhost, the main company Exchange server.  `servicebot@example.com` and `servicebot@asriel.example.com` are the only addresses in the `example.com` domain that should be handled by the `asriel` host, and they should be sent to the local `davidw` account as listed in `/etc/aliases`.

But since `$mydomain` is in the list of `$mydestination`, any outgoing email that my servicebot generates (e.g. to johndoe@example.com) gets delivered to a local mail account, not sent to the relayhost.  That's not what I want.

I thought the solution would be simple: remove `$mydomain` from the `mydestination` list, and include `$myhostname.$mydomain` instead.  I hoped this would force mail sent to `asriel.example.com` to be handled as a local delivery, and send any other outgoing mail `@example.com` to the relayhost.

However, this isn't working as I hoped.  Mail arrives on the box intended for `servicebot@asriel.example.com`, but is not delivered locally.  Instead it's immediately sent away to the relayhost.

```
Sep 26 14:06:45 asriel postfix/smtpd[123702]: connect from mailmain-exch01.example.com[203.0.113.1]
Sep 26 14:06:45 asriel postfix/smtpd[123702]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
Sep 26 14:06:45 asriel postfix/smtpd[123702]: discarding EHLO keywords: CHUNKING
Sep 26 14:06:46 asriel postfix/smtpd[123702]: 062FBCC128E: client=mailmain-exch01.example.com[203.0.113.1]
Sep 26 14:06:46 asriel postfix/cleanup[123809]: 062FBCC128E: message-id=<20230926190645.8B6FE1820B@webmain01.example.com>
Sep 26 14:06:46 asriel postfix/qmgr[88692]: 062FBCC128E: from=<johndoe@webmain01.example.com>, size=1843, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 26 14:06:46 asriel postfix/smtp[123815]: 062FBCC128E: to=<servicebot@example.com>, orig_to=<servicebot@asriel.example.com>, relay=outbound.example.com[203.0.113.250]:25, delay=0.31, delays=0.18/0.02/0.03/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, 
status=sent (250 2.0.0 38QJ6kFu003826 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 26 14:06:46 asriel postfix/qmgr[88692]: 062FBCC128E: removed
```

I suspect this is because the **`to`** field shows `servicebot@example.com`, while the **`orig_to`** field shows `servicebot@asriel.example.com`.  I thought maybe that adding `$myhostname.$mydomain` to `main.cf`, then removing `$mydomain` would cause the server to handle mail sent directly to this host, but I'm guessing that the mail routing is done based on the **`to`** field rather than **`orig_to`**.

So how can I configure Postfix to handle only (1) incoming local mail and (2) send incoming mail to either `servicebot@example.com` or `servicebot@asriel.example.com` to the local `davidw` account, and send all non-local mail (which is pretty much everything except for root mail) to the relayhost?

Comment: Some configuration on the server rewrites `orig_to=<servicebot@asriel.example.com>` as `to=<servicebot@example.com`, but you haven't shared that configuration.

Comment: When a user sends email to `servicebot@example.com`, the Exchange server remaps it to `servicebot@asriel.cisco.com` and sends it on to my server.  So the message headers of the incoming email shows `Return-Path: <johndoe@webmain01.example.com>`, `X-Original-To: servicebot@asriel.example.com`, `Delivered-To: servicebot@example.com`, `To: servicebot@example.com`

Comment: After Exchange remaps it to `servicebot@asriel.example.com` and transfers to this Postfix instance, Postfix remaps it again into `servicebot@example.com`  (and successfully deliveries to smtp:[utbound.example.com]). This is what we read in your logs. So, please show a **complete** configuration as output by `postconf -n`, not a part of it you assume is "enough", *and* include contents of any external files that define alias expansion.

Comment: That said, the easiest and cleanest configuration you'll achieve if you declare there's a domain which this server will handle; all the domain, not just a couple of addresses in it. Pick a name that is unlikely to be needed elsewhere. and set it as both `myhostname` and `mydomain`. Alternative would be to play with `transport_maps` but I don't see enough reasoning to justify increasing configuration complexity that much.

Comment: This was the correct suggestion; my company had inserted custom configuration elsewhere which included `masquerade_domains = example.com`.  This turned `servicebot@asriel.example.com` back to `servicebot@example.com`, which then got sent to the relayhost.  Getting rid of the `masquerade_domains` solved the problem.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it. It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Comment: Yeah, might as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as Nikita suspected, was additional unexpected Postfix directives added as boilerplate by my company.  One of its directives was `masquerade_domains = example.com`. This turned `servicebot@asriel.example.com` back into `servicebot@example.com`, which then got sent to the relayhost. Getting rid of the `masquerade_domains` directive solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have pretty much the same setup, I don't have much configured.

```
mydestination = localhost.example.com, localhost
relayhost = smtp.example.com

virtual_mailbox_domains = jira.example.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/atlassian/files/jira/import/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
```

Just this is sufficient. Emails coming from Exchange are delivered to the mailbox, outgoing mails are delivered to Exchange via the relay host.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but but I would try to rewrite the recipient with

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport 

/etc/postfix/transport:
    servicebot@asriel.example.com       virtual:davidw@localhost
    servicebot@example.com              virtual:davidw@localhost
    *     relay:[exchange.example.com]:587
```

This might need ...

```
mydomain = asriel.example.com
```

(but note that this has the side effect of using "asriel.example.com" as the envelope FROM address if none is specified).